# PHP use regular expression to validate data input

Tags: php, regex

My users have a cookie with a string called code in it, the code is just random numbers or letters between 6 and 15 characters long.  How after I receive the code, how can I check to ensure that the code is between 6 and 15 characters long and only contains numbers and letters?

Is using regular expressions the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy ways you can do this. One is using regular expressions:

```
$length = strlen($cookie);
if (6 <= $length && $length <= 15 && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $cookie)) {
    //...
}
```

The other is using the built-in [ctype_alnum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function which does exactly that (making sure a string is alpha-numeric):

```
$length = strlen($cookie);
if (6 <= $length && $length <= 15 && ctype_alnum($cookie)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like : `^([a-zA-Z]|\d){6,15}$`

“between the beginning and the end of the string, there are between 6 and 15 characters, each of them a letter or a digit”.

And, oh, the function you need is [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

php's regex is pretty quick, and this is a case of a simple selector:

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15}$/"
```

But @amosrivera was right about `strlen` being faster. If the cookie data is being plugged in the page (`echo $_COOKIE['key'];`) then the XML entities wont matter as the user can only harm **their own page**. If the cookie is being stored in a database and being displayed for all users, it would be a different matter altogether.